# AppcompatActivity is not recognised

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, appcompatactivity

i am using Android Studio and despite all the projects in the old projects folder are working fine, when i try to 
create a new project, AS could not recognise AppCompatActivity class

please have a look at the build.gradle and the style folders

please let em know how solve it

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

**style**:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

**update: after : com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
 Required by:
     MyApplication4:app:unspecified
  > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
     > Could not get resource  
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-  
 v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom'.
        > Could not GET  
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-
v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom'.
           > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

Comment: Just try `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

Comment: @MD please see update section above